A net without sequences as subnets

Let $F(\Bbb{R})$ the family of all finite subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ and consider the net of $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{R}}$ defined by $S=\{S_F: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R} \, | \, F \in F(\Bbb{R}) \}$ where $S_F$ denotes the characteristic map of $F$ . Prove that there is no sequence who is subnet of $S$ .

I am trying to prove this but it seems more difficult than I thought.
First of all, the definition of subnet I know is:

Given a net $(S,D)$, we say that $(S',D')$ is a subnet of $(S,D)$ if $\forall d_0 \in D \, \exists d'_0 \in D' \, \forall d' \geq d'_0 \, \exists d \geq d_0 : S_d = S'_{d'}$

I intuit that this can be done by contradiction, supposing that there is a sequence who is subnet of $S$, but I do not have any idea on how to reach that contradiction. I thought that maybe it can be used on someway that $F(\Bbb{R})$, and therefore $S$, has cardinality greater or equal than $\Bbb{R}$ since the injection $\Bbb{R} \rightarrow F(\Bbb{R}), x \mapsto \{x\}$ , but I am not seeing it, so any possible help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)
EDIT
Let $1 : \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ defined by $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}: 1(x) = 1$ . If we denote $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}$ the map $ev_x : \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R} , f \mapsto f(x)$ we can define the set $\Sigma = \{ ev^{-1}_x (U) \, | \, x \in \Bbb{R} \, \land \, U \in \mathcal{T}_u \}$ which will generate a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{R}}$ .
If $V \in \varepsilon(x)$ is open, then there is a family $A \subseteq F(\Bbb{R})$ and $\{ U_{F,x} : F \in A \, \land \, x \in F \}$ such that $$V = \bigcup_{F \in A} \bigcap_{x \in F} ev^{-1}_x (U_{F,x})$$
Since $1 \in V$, there is $F_0 \in A$ such that $1 \in \cap_{x \in F_0} ev^{-1}_x ( U_{F_0 , x} )$. That is, $\forall x \in F_0 : 1 \in U_{F_0, x}$ . Then, given $F \in F(\Bbb{R}): F_0 \subseteq F$, it has that $\forall x \in F_0: S_F(x)=1$ and then $S_F \in V$. This proves that $S \rightarrow 1$ in $\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{R}$ .
In other words, we have prove that $$(1) \hspace{1cm} \forall V \in \varepsilon(1) \, \exists F_0 \in F(\Bbb{R}) \, \forall F \supseteq F_0 : S_F \in V$$
The problem is, if $\{x_n\} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{R}$ is a subnet of $S$, by definition $$(2) \hspace{1cm} \forall F_0 \in F(\Bbb{R}) \, \exists n_0 \in \Bbb{N} \, \forall n \geq n_0 \, \exists F \supseteq F_0 : x_n = S_F$$ Does not $(1)$ and $(2)$ together implies that $x_n \rightarrow 1$ ?

If a net $(x_\alpha){\alpha\in I}$ is convergent,say to $y$, then its subnets are also convergent to $y$. If no sequence in the set ${x\alpha,\alpha\in I}$ converges to $y$, then the net does not possess a subnet that is a sequence.

Alternatively you can consider the underlying directed set, and show directly that there is no cofinal subset, which is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

@OnurOktay Thanks for your advice! I suspect that the map $1 : \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, x  \mapsto 1$ should work for this, but, if I do not bother you with my question, which is the topology of $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{R}}$ ? Does it come induced by a map?

Perhaps you mean the product topology. If so, yes, the limit of this net is 1.

@OnurOktay Could you please tell me if I did something wrong? It seems confusing to me due to the mix of complex concepts

If there existed a subsequence $(S_{F_n})$, then $S_{F_n}\leq S_E$ pointwise for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $E=\bigcup_m F_m$. As $n\to\infty$, we would have $1\leq S_E$. This is a contradiction since $E$ is a countable set.

@OnurOktay I do not understand, what order are you using on $S$ ? Is the inclusion of the finite sets?

pointwise order of functions. Note also the product topology is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence.

This question has nothing to do with topology and convergence. Certainly one can define a topology on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ and then ask whether the net $S$ converges, but it is irrelevant here.
In the sequel recall that $F' \ge F$ in $F(\mathbb R)$ iff $F' \supset F$.
Assume that there exists a sequence $\Sigma  = \{\Sigma_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ which is a subnet of $S$. Then for $F_0 = \emptyset$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ there exists $F(n) \in F(\mathbb R)$ with $F(n) \supset \emptyset $ and $S_{F(n)} = \Sigma_n$.
The set $E = \bigcup_{n \ge n_0} F(n)$ is countable. Pick $x \in \mathbb R \setminus E$. Since $\Sigma$ is a subnet of $S$, for $G_0 = \{x\}$ there exists $m_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $m \ge m_0$ there exists $G(m) \in F(\mathbb R)$ with $G(m) \supset G_0$ and $S_{G(m)} = \Sigma_m$. Let $M = \max(n_0,m_0)$. Then $S_{G(M)} = \Sigma_M = S_{F(M)}$ which means $G(M) = F(M)$. But $x \notin E$ which implies $x \notin F(M)$. This contradicts
$x \in G_0 \subset G(M) = F(M)$.

Thanks you for your answer!
